# What was the fate of Dior Eluchil?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

Dior was the second King of Doriath and the son of Beren and Lúthien, so that made him half man, half elf and Maia. However, since Dior died before Manwë decreed any half-blood person could choose which kindred they wanted to be with, what was his fate?

Did he dwell in the Halls of Mandos with the Elves or did he go beyond the circles of Arda like Men do?

Comment: Like Luca Braza, swimming with the fishes ... and Ulmo.

Comment: user8719's answer basically sums up any potential answer to this: without a special exemption (which we don't know of in this case), any half-elf not descended from Eärendil is considered mortal